# Combining and Compressing multiple JavaScript files into a single file in a Django project

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, ember.js

What is the simplest way to combine JavaScript files into a single file in a Django project?

**Explanation**

I want this to work with Ember.js/Backbone where you (usually) have many different JavaScript in multiple directories. Directories would all be in one folder called app/ for example, like: app/views/ app/models/ /app/routers/

**Requirements**

- Work together with the staticfiles app
- Still be separated while in development mode for easier debugging (only compile when calling collectstatic?)
- Work with Require.js (guess that shouldn't be too hard, but putting it in here to be sure)

**Extra credit**

Explain a best practices way of combining Django and Ember/Backbone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am an happy user of django compressor, it does combine, minify, debug-friendly, you can use it with staticfiles, easy to plug with custom storage backend (eg. S3)

https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor

Answer (score 1):

The reason you want to combine many files into one is so to minimize latency of setting up and tearing down http requests, the fewer you make the better. However, many newer browsers are downloading JavaScript files in parallel (still executing sequentially). The consequence is that downloading a single 1Mb file may be slower than three 350Kb files.

you can use from CDNs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, django-compressor is nice, but you often get better loading times when using a dedicated javascript loader instead. My tip is to check out Head.js for example (http://headjs.com/) (there are tons other out there as well). Often combining scripts can be contra productive when considering caching, using javascript located on CDN:s etc.

One thing to remember is that Iphone 3/4 will just cache 15/25KB of javascript, so if you have huge scripts and combine them you can run into trouble. http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/